# How to use curl with ajax in Nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, curl

I am working with nodejs,I want to fetch data from api(in other server),So i am using ajax with curl
But i am not getting data.Where i am wrong ? Here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
    url: "example.com/get_viewed_candidates",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password")); 
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    data: '{"foo":"bar"}',
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: That's not a complete code,check for browser console and paste your errors here

Comment: Where in this code are you using `curl`? `curl` is a CLI tool. Were you refering to `jquery` instead?

Comment: Along with the errors from the browser's console, you should also add the controller for that function in the Node backend service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't request to another url/endpoint directly as you implemented above due to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` policy. If you want to achieve this you have to allow your request from your serverside. Once you enabled it from server side client side will send multiple requests 1 to validate the request and another for getting information if everything is validated.

Comment: It's not clear if he's making the request to another domain or the same. `example.com` could very well be the host form where this script is being served.

Comment: @FranciscoHanna: i am saying about another domain

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding of the concept, read about Same-origin policy and CORS as below -

**Same-origin policy** -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

**CORS** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS